# Error in program to find the Armstrong numbers between intervals given by the user

Tags: c++, scope, do-while

Error:

> //Count(variable) not declared! error.

But I have declared it. This is a program to calculate the number of Armstrong digits in the interval given by the user. It will continue to run until there is at least one Armstrong number in the interval. I have used a Do-While loop for this purpose.

C++:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>  

using namespace std;

//Function to check if the number is an Armstrong number
bool Armstrong(int n) {
    int number, original, remainder, result = 0, k = 0;
    original = n;
    //Calculating the number of digits
    while (original != 0) {
        original /= 10;
        ++k;
    }

    original = n;

    while (original != 0) {
        remainder = original % 10;
        result += pow(remainder, k);
        original /= 10;
    }

    if (result == n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//Checking Armstrong in the interval
int main() {
    do {
        int start, stop, n, i = 1;
        std::cout << "Enter Starting Point: ";
        std::cin >> start;
        std::cout << "Enter Stop Point: ";
        std::cin >> stop;
        n = start;
        int count = 0; //printing the numbers in the interval
        for (; start <= stop; start++) {
            if (Armstrong(start)) {
                std::cout << "Armstrong Number " << i << " : " << start;
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            n--;
        }
        //It is showing the error here. "Count not Declared"
    }
    while (count == 0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly, when asking questions about build errors, please copy-paste (as text) the *full* and *complete* error output into the question itself.

Comment: And a hint about your problem: Remember that scope ends with `}`. Variables defined inside a block doesn't exists past the closing `}`.

Comment: please make sure you post the exact code and error message. There is no `Count` in your code. Details do matter, because if you declare a `count` there is still no declaration for `Count`

Comment: function names should be lower case. you should declare an index so start doesn't change in the loop

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you declare `int count;` inside the `do-while` loop, so you can't check for it in the loop condition. Move it to outside of the loop:

```
int count = 0;
    do {
        int start, stop, n, i = 1;
        ...
    } while (count == 0);
```